# php zend framework rows affected

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using zend framework and I see save() function used in the code, would like to know if there is a way to get the rows affected after this to see number of rows affected ..

I checked this [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html#zend.db.table.rowset.to-array) but din't help much. any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Zend_Db_Table_Row::save() method returns the primary key of the row, either the current primary key if you're updating an existing row, or a new primary key if you're saving a new row.

The save() method applies to one row instance, so as @Evernoob says it should only apply to one row.  But it doesn't necessarily result in one row "affected" when you save.  For instance, if I haven't changed any column values, and I save() a row, the rows affected is zero.  Try something like this in the mysql shell and you'll see it reports zero rows affected.

```
UPDATE mytable SET column1 = column1 WHERE id = 1234; -- effectively a noop
```

The Zend_Db_Statement has a method `rowCount()` (mimicking the PDOStatement [`rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) method), but this information is not surfaced through the Zend_Db_Table_Row interface.

So if you need that information, you'll have to update your data using Zend_Db_Adapter::query() to create a Zend_Db_Statement object.  After you execute() the statement, you can call rowCount() on it.

Comment: oh thanks for the clarification..thats why when i tried rowcount(), it din't work..

Answer (score 1):

the save() function is applied to the instance of that object, which is associated with one row.  You can therefore safely assume that calling save() on an object will only affect its one associated row.

Comment: ok thanks, but even with that can i know if it affected that record or not? because for reasons like if the db was not reachable then i want to abort by checking if it affected the record or not..if its not then i will abort it.